# HTTP for images between client and server sends empty stream

Tags: rest, http, blazor, webassembly, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to send a stream (containing an image file) from a WASM client to a backend .NET Core 5 server.  In the WASM app, I start with a MemoryStream that contains the file data.  In order to send the data contained in this MemoryStream using HttpClient.PostAsync, I seem to have to convert it to a StreamContent object:

```
StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(imageMemoryStream);
```

I use the debugger to verify that the length of the content of streamContent is not zero at this point.  So far so good.

I then use HttpClient.PostAsync to send this stream to the server:

```
var response = await Http.PostAsync("api/HttpStreamReceiver", streamContent);
```

On the server side, I have a controller that receives HTTP messages:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HttpStreamReceiverController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
    {
        Stream imageStream;
        try
        {
             imageStream = Request.Body;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             return new BadRequestObjectResult("Error saving file");
        }
    }
}
```

Here, it seems that Request.Body is empty.  Trying to evaluate the length of either Request.Body or of imageStream on the server side results in a System.NotSupportedException, and

```
await imageStream.ReadAsync(buffer);
```

leaves buffer blank.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The image file cannot be transmitted through the body unless it is serialized. I suggest you use `MultipartFormDataContent` to pass the file.

This is an example.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"D:\upload\images\1.png";
        HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        string _url = "https://localhost:44324/api/HttpStreamReceiver/";
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));
        }
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"File [{filePath}] not found.");
        }

        //Create form
        using var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        byte[] buffur = new byte[fs.Length];
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(buffur);

        //var bytefile = AuthGetFileData(filePath);
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffur);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
        form.Add(fileContent, "image", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

        //the other data in form
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"{_url}", form);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
        bw.Close();
    }
}
```

Web api.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HttpStreamReceiverController: ControllerBase
{
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Get(IFormFile image)
        {
            //...
            return Ok("get");
        }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This needs to use BinaryReader instead of BinaryWriter.  Using BinaryRighter fills the byte array with all zeroes.

Comment: You can convert the file to base64.  Then decode it in the api.

Comment: Yes, but I think you meant to use "BinaryReader" instead of "BinaryWriter" in your answer.  Even with that conversion the data is not sent, but if you replace "BinaryWriter" with "BinaryReader" it works.

Comment: Ok, I will test it.